# Sending the file output to user desktop as open/save/cancel using java

Tags: java, file, jsp

I am using an api which checkout the file from server and writes the data to `java.io.OutputStream`. Below is the code.

```
BusinessObject bObj = new BusinessObject(request.getParameter("objectId"));     
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/"+request.getParameter("fileName"));     
bObj.checkoutFile(context, false, "generic", request.getParameter("fileName"), output);
```

It is actually writing the data to the server `C:` drive. Instead i want to send this to the user desktop with options to `open/save/cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the path:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
```